# sum of all transactions if date = June

Tags: excel

I have a list off transactions with the date in column B and total amount for the transaction in column I. I want to have a cell that contains sum total of all transactions in the month of June of year 2011. However, the dates in column B may not be all in June, so I need to filter months that are June and then add all the values for each transaction of that month.

My thinking, `=IF(DATE(2011,06,*),SUM(VLOOKUP(.....), Null))`
, `=SUM(IF(B=Date(2011,06,*))`

Can you help me out please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the `SUMIF()` function? That might be a start.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i understand the function but adding another function inside of it is the problem. this is what i have: =SUMIF(I3:I63,B3:B63,"DATE(2011,06,*)").

Comment: What i have now is: =SUMIF(I3:I63,DATE(2011,07,">=1"<=30"),B3:B63)
Still cant figure it out, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(B3:B63,"mmm-yyyy")="jun-2011")+0,I3:I63)`

...or if you have Excel 2007 or later SUMIFS is probably preferable

`=SUMIFS(I3:I63,B3:B63,">="&DATE(2011,6,1),B3:B63,"<"&DATE(2011,7,1))`

or with first of relevant month in a cell, e.g. A1 you can make that more flexible

`=SUMIFS(I3:I63,B3:B63,">="&A1,B3:B63,"<"&EOMONTH(A1,0)+1)`

Comment: looks like it worked, =SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(B3:B63,"mm/yyyy")="06/2011")+0,I3:I63)

Date in column B is in format dd/mm/yyyy (if this changes anything)

tried with some dummy date with date 11/2011 - works. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with an Array Formula. Something like this where your transactions are in `A2:A6` and your dates are in `B2:B6`. This will return the sum of all transactions in June 2011.

```
{=SUM((MONTH($B$2:$B$6)=6)*(YEAR($B$2:$B$6)=2011)*($A$2:$A$6))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested code, works fine for me.

so if A1 = 06/01/2010

```
=if(MONTH(A1)=6, SUM(VLOOKUP(.....), Null), SUM(I(IF(B=Date(2011,06,)))))
```